# dynamic window title from command input (TCSH)

Tags: xterm, tcsh, window-title

I am looking for a way to dynamically set the window title based on the command input.

For instance, if I run `elinks` I want the window title to be set to `elinks`.

I did search a lot, but all the info relates to  `bash`.

How can this be done with `tcsh`?
Maybe the `-v` or the `-x` switch comes in here somehow?

Answer (score 2):

A quick look through the fine manual for `tcsh(1)` turns up:

```
   postcmd Runs before each command gets executed.

               > alias postcmd  'echo -n "^[]2\;\!#:q^G"'

           then executing vi foo.c will put  the  command  string  in  the
           xterm title bar.
```

Granted, the `BEL` and `ESC` characters in that documentation are probably not in a form suitable for copy-n-paste, and some vendors may set a custom prompt by default that then overrides any escape codes done by the alias:

```
...$ echo $prompt
%%[%n@%m %c]%#
...$ set prompt = '> '
> alias postcmd 'echo -n "\033]2;\!#:q\007"'
>
```

Comment: Thank you. Found it. Actually, it would be `jobcmd`. But it's not working, either.